# Position inner DIV outside containing DIV - Inner DIV size is unkown - CSS solution Needed

Tags: html, css, webkit

How can I position an absolute positioned DIV within a relative positioned DIV, where the inner DIV should appear on upper left side of the outer DIV.

My issue is that the size of the inner DIV is still yet unknown. I want the entire width of the inner div to be at the top-left side, outside the outer DIV, including any padding that the outer DIV might have.

Here's an illustration of what I want to achieve:

[image]

This might be possible to do with jQuery, but I want a CSS solution. It will run on webkit browser only, so no need for Internet explorer support. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need `position: absolute`? http://jsbin.com/befeh/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with css only :

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">
 </div>
</div>
```

The trick is to apply `right: 100%;`

```
.outer {
    background: #333;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/H7QAe/